# Read Elevation from 1/3 Arc-Second NED .tif or .img

Tags: geotiff-tiff, elevation

I'm trying to read multiple elevations from a USGS 1/3 arc-second IMG / GeoTIFF file.

A sample of the files is available here (5 MB):
http://tdds3.cr.usgs.gov/Ortho9/ned/ned_13/img/n43w108.zip

I can query the .img file and get the elevation using GDAL:
gdallocationinfo -wgs84 imgn60w145_13.img -144.267361111152354 59.9981944444444082

This returns:
Report:
  Location: (7918P,25L)
  Band 1:
    Value: 1.2593731880188

Because a GeoTIFF can be read quite a bit faster than an IMG file (in my benchmarks) I convert the IMG to a WGS84 GeoTIFF:
gdal_translate -a_srs WGS84 -of GTiff imgn60w145_13.img imgn60w145_13.tif

gdallocationinfo only supports querying one point at a time.  I need to get the elevation every 10 meters between 2 points (along a straight path), so I'm trying to read the file directly, with the following PHP code (but the approach is the same in C or Python):

> `$STRIPOFFSETS = 230; // 0xe6
> $LEN_OFFSET = 4;
>
> $DATA_VOID = 0x8000;    // data void ( = signed int -32768)
> $LEN_DATA = 4; // the number of bytes containing each item of elevation data // ( = BitsPerSample tag value / 8) 
>
> $fp = fopen("imgn60w145_13.tif", 'rb');
> if ($fp === false) {
>     echo "Could not open the file\n";
> }
>
> // first data offset
> fseek($fp, $STRIPOFFSETS);
>
> // find the location of the required data row in the StripOffsets data    
> $dataOffset = $STRIPOFFSETS + ($row * $LEN_OFFSET);
> fseek($fp, $dataOffset);
> $dataBytes = fread($fp, $LEN_OFFSET);       
> $data = unpack('VdataOffset', $dataBytes);
> echo print_r($data, true);
>
> // this is the offset of the 1st column in the required data row
> $firstColOffset = $data['dataOffset'];
>
> // now work out the required column offset relative to the 1st column      
> $requiredColOffset = $col * $LEN_DATA;
>
> // combine the two and read the elevation data at that address 
> fseek($fp, $firstColOffset + $requiredColOffset);
> $dataBytes = fread($fp, $LEN_DATA); 
> echo "1: " . $firstColOffset . " + " . $requiredColOffset . "\n";
> echo "2: " . $LEN_DATA . "\n";
> echo "3: " . $dataBytes . "\n";      
> $data = unpack('velevation', $dataBytes);
>
> $elevation = $data['elevation'];       
> if ($elevation == $DATA_VOID) {
>     $elevation = 0;
> }
> echo $elevation . "\n";`

I don't know that I have the right values for `$STRIPOFFSETS`, `$LEN_OFFSET`, or `$LEN_DATA`.  The code above is a limited snippet from SRTMGeoTIFFReader (http://www.osola.org.uk/elevations/index.htm), which I'm not able to get to work either.

I'd really prefer to be able to do this using a direct approach similar to the above (no external libraries, etc), but I can live with a Python / GDAL approach as well.

Thanks!

Comment: GDAL would be good for this, you can open the raster and read the block (extent) and then index the rows from the returned array. I don't know PHP so can't help any further.. sorry. Another option is BIL format which can be read directly as a binary file. The data is stored as just data and can be indexed as such if it's in the right coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks, BIL was just the nudge I needed.  Much easier than GeoTiff (no offsets to deal with), and lightning fast.

Comment: You're welcome. I've used BIL format for just that reason myself, also the other way around - it's easy to write to the binary at file offsets and the header is just text... that was before GDAL though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to convert the files to BIL files using GDAL:

`gdal_translate -a_srs NAD83 -of EHdr file.img file.bil`

This created .bil and .hdr files.  The .hdr file contains the details you need to determine where to read the file.  I was then able to get the elevation using the PHP unpack function. Performance is lightning fast.

Comment: Are you able to give a code sample of your solution using unpack()? I am trying to get the elevation for a lat/lon from a NED img file.

Comment: There is a lot more to this (determining which row, which column, getting NCOLS from the .hdr, but this should work:  `$bil = fopen('file.bil', 'rb');
$NCOLS = 3601;
$col = 1;
$row = 1;
fseek($bil, ($col * 4) + ($row * $NCOLS * 4));
$dataBytes = fread(bil, 4);
$data = unpack('f', $dataBytes);
echo $data['1'] . " meters\n";`